# QSettings: Copy, modify but avoid changing underlying .ini file

Tags: qt, qsettings

I read some `QSettings` from an .ini file:

```
QSettings* settingsDocRoot=new QSettings(_settingsFile ,QSettings::IniFormat, parent);
```

This is passed to some object. However, I then do a copy `QSettings* s2= new QSettings(settingsDocRoot);` and modify one particular value `s2->setValue("path", whateverNewPath);`

Basically I want to pass a slightly modified `QSettings` object to another object. But how do I **avoid that the original ini file is updated** with the changed value (`s2->setValue`)?

One idea was, simply to set the path to "". However, according to [QSettings - where is the location of the ini file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031838/qsettings-where-is-the-location-of-the-ini-file) then a default location will be assumed (OK, original file will not be changed, but unnecessary file will be written).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am currently doing the following:

```
    QSettings* settingsWsNaviGraph = new QSettings(settingsDocRoot);
    // avoid writing to file
    settingsWsNaviGraph->setPath(QSettings::InvalidFormat, QSettings::UserScope, "");
```

This dirty hack seems to avoid writing, at least my original file remains unchanged and I do not see any unwanted file yet (will report if I do find one).

If this here does not work, I'll try to register my own format with bogus read/write methods. See [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/29445-QSettings-custom-format-and-class-methods-as-read-write-functions)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work in the latest Qt 5.12.

Answer (score 3):

QSettings is entirely designed for persistence.  If you don't want your copy to write to disk, you'd probably be better off copying all the values into a QHash and passing that to your other object:

```
QHash<QString, QVariant> hash;
const QStringList keys = settings->allKeys();
Q_FOREACH(QString key, keys) {
  hash[key] = settings->value(key());
}
```

Comment: Nice idea, need to test it, because the class I am passing the QSettings to, is not written by me and cannot be modified.

Comment: I do not see a way to pass QHash / QMap to a signature with QSettings, do you?