# How to store in Qt Settings?

Tags: qt

I am currently creating a dialog with a check box that says "Do no display again". When the check box is clicked and the dialog is closed (ok button pressed), the application will store in `QSettings` that this dialog box has been opened before.

I'm not familiar with Qt settings and looking at the API, I don't know which function to use.

Could anyone point me to the right direction? Thank you!

Btw I did try `QErrorMessage`, but the message box keeps popping up so I gave up on it.

```
void MessageBox::on_checkBox_stateChanged(int arg1)
{
    if(ui->checkBox->stateChanged(arg1) && ui->pushButton->clicked(true))
    //I believe this is right.
    {
       writeSettings();
    }
}

void MessageBox::writeSettings()
{
    QSettings settings;
//...help; Question: Should I write in main.cpp or in the .h?
}

void MessageBox::readSettings()
{
//...help
}
```

Comment: have a look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/q/3597900/2796, you should find the answer you are looking for regarding the usage of `QSettings`.

Comment: @Jérôme Thank you! :) I will keep that tabbed as a reference!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use the QSettings constructor in this form, you must set the organization and application name for your application, probably in main.cpp if you create it there:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
a.setOrganizationName("MySoft");
a.setApplicationName("Star Runner");
```

Then in your writeSettings() you do:

```
QSettings settings;
settings.setValue("showErrorMessages", ui->checkBox->isChecked());
```

and in readSettings()

```
QSettings settings;
bool showErrorMessages = settings.value("showErrorMessages", true).toBool()
```

It's all in the [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsettings.html#details) and explained quite clearly IMO.

Comment: Really, wow, I was wondering what was the purpose for set value and how to use it. Now just a quick question to someone who started using qt a month ago lol, where you have `a.setOrganizationName()`  and `a.setAplicationName()`. Will that overwrite the current names i.e. `MainWidow::setWindowTitle("example")`?