# Qt File Dialog doesn't remember the last directory after restarting project

Tags: c++, qt, qfiledialog, qsettings

I'm loading some files for my project....but every time the fileDialog directory is my root directory...

I want the fileDialog to remember my path and I've tried the solution in the following link [qsettings-file-chooser-should-remember-the-last-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597900/qsettings-file-chooser-should-remember-the-last-directory) but this worked for me for the same session only.

Is there a way to save the directory for other sessions?(when closing the application and re-opening it)?

Comment: Try saving the value into an ini file. And load it back when you reopen the app.

Comment: I 'm not sure if I know how to do it, I'm fairly new with Qt but I'll try...

Comment: The link you provided in your question gives you everything you need to persist this information accross runs. Correctly set your app information in your main() function, then you can simply uses a QSettings instance to persist the information.

Comment: What app information should I set ?...I couldn't find anything related

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the QSettings class.
This is simple example:
**widget.h**

```
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QSettings>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();

private:
    QString lastDir;
    QSettings *settings;
    void settingsLoader();
    void settingsSaver();
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

**widget.cpp**

```
#include <QFileDialog>
#include "widget.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    settings = new QSettings("MyCompany", "My soft name", this);
    settingsLoader();
    lastDir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Open directory"), lastDir);
}

void Widget::settingsLoader()
{
    lastDir = settings->value("LastDir", QDir::homePath()).toString();
}

void Widget::settingsSaver()
{
    settings->setValue("LastDir", lastDir);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    settingsSaver();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I know what's the  difference between  the code in my question and your answer but it worked !
Thanks a lot..